# separating and pooling equilibrium

Tags: microeconomics

A population is made of two types of individuals: healthy and unhealthy. The share of healthy individuals is $Z \in (0, 1)$ . Healthy individuals get sick with probability $\beta_H \in (0, 1)$ and unhealthy individuals get sick with probability $\beta_U \in (0, 1)$ . We assume that $\beta_H < \beta_U$ . An individuals who gets sick experiences a loss $u (-l) < 0$ with respect to their regular utility, which we normalize to $u (0) = 0$. We assume that $u$ is an increasing and concave function.
Individuals can buy a health insurance in a perfectly competitive insurance market. The insurance contract works as follows. Individuals pay a monetary premium $p$ to buy the insurance and if they
get unhealthy, the insurance cover the loss $l$. The utility of an insured individual is thus $u (0) = 0$ independently of whether they gets sick or not. The insurance company has linear utility over money and it aims at maximizing the amount of money.

(a) Assume there is complete information about the health condition of individuals. What would the insurance company do? What would be the equilibrium utility of the two individuals?

(b) Assume that before signing the insurance contract, individuals can display effort. Effort does not decrease the probability of getting sick. The effort cost function of physical activity is

$c_H (e) =\frac{e^2}{4}$

$c_U (e) =\frac{ e^2}{2}$

Characterize the pooling and separating equilibria of this model.